# How to check if the column is null or full?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this query:

```
 $posts = Post::query()
                 ->where('active',true)
                 ->where('expire_date','>', now())
                 ->latest()
                 ->get();
```

the `expire_date` column is `nullable`, and what I need in query is get all posts where the active one and check  `expire_date` is null get all of them, but if the `expire_date` is set the date check that date is expired or not!

How can say if the column is set check the expire date and if null get them!

Comment: Can you share what did you tried?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur  above in the code!

Comment: exists query, checks whether make data  exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using `orWhere` on [parameter group](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#parameter-grouping)

```
$posts = Post::query()
    ->where('active', true)
    ->where(
        function ($query) {
            $query->whereNull('expire_date')
                ->orWhere('expire_date', '>', now());
        }
    )
    ->latest()
    ->get();
```